# How do implement Event Tracking on a site built with Classic ASP

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, google-analytics, event-tracking

I need to implement Google Analytics Event Tracking on a website built in classic asp.

As I am n00b I assumed this would be achievable with a few simple includes. e.g.

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '<% =category %>', '<% =action %>']);"
```

I have been skooled.  Unfortunately I have no idea what to do next, beyond moving away from ASP (which is not possible). Any suggestions or advice would be gratefully received.

Comment: Event tracking is all client side, are there script errors? the cause of your problem is most likely something the rendered output so you would need to show/link that.

Comment: In truth I've not tried it yet, just was told it wouldn't work and asked to come back with a different solution. Will try it myself now. Thanks.

Comment: That looks just fine to me... whoever told you it wouldn't work clearly hadn't tried it :)

Comment: Got it work, thanks for your help. Have a feeling it was being deflected with waffle, but it means I had to try it out myself and got it working. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code should work, provided you've set `category` and `action`; be mindful though that you escape single quotes (`'`):

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '<%=Replace(category, "'", "\'") %>', '<%=Replace(action, "'", "\'") %>']);"
```